# Is the phrase "a brute of a husband" a figure of speech?

Tags: figures-of-speech

I came across the phrase "A BRUTE OF A HUSBAND". I would normally use 'a brute husband', and this construction seems interesting to me. However, I don't know how to search for more phrases like this, because if I write down "of a" in google I would get the normal sentences we all know.

Does this way of speaking have a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an idiomatic usage:

***[of a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20a)***

- idiom
  (US, informal)

> —used to indicate that someone or something is a particular type of person or thing.

Usage examples:

> her idiot of a husband
>
> It is not that much of a problem.
>
> It wasn't that difficult of a shot.
>
> How big of a piece do you want?

(M-W)

Comment: As a British English speaker, I wouldn't use _of_ in the last two examples - but expressions like _a giant of a man, a darling of a child_ are well-established.

Comment: Indeed, usually it's a noun of a noun.